# API Error when saving permissions

Tags: civirules

We are on civi 4.7.22 and Wordpress 4.8.22

We attempting to save permissions in Users and Permissions. I get this Error at the end of the process 
" ***Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
API (CiviRuleAction, get) does not exist (join the API team and implement it!)"***
I have searched and I can't find anything that explains this.
Is anyone here familiar with it?
Thank you.

Comment: This is related to an extension - perhaps CiviRules or - I have a suspicion - my very own Fast Action Links.  Can you please a) list the extensions you have installed, and b) mention which, if any, are disabled?

Comment: I've seen similar messages where CiviRules is installed but disabled.

Comment: Thank you for your responses.  The extensions we have enabled are: Simple Donate, Angular Profiles, CiviDiscount and CiviVolunteer.  We do have CiviRules disabled.  If that is the problem, how should I resolve it?

Comment: If civirules is only disabled, then there will be an uninstall link, use that.